# operator== container iterator const and non-const

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, containers

I'm trying to have an eventmanager for the impossibly fast c++ delegate that was discussed in this article http://blog.coldflake.com/posts/C++-delegates-on-steroids/;

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Params>
class delegate<R (T::*)(Params...) const>
{
public:
    typedef R (T::*func_type)(Params...) const;

    delegate(func_type func, const T& callee)
        : callee_(callee) , func_(func)
    {}

    R operator()(Params... args) const
    { return (callee_.*func_)(args...); }

    bool operator==(const delegate& other) const
    { return (&callee_ == &other.callee_) && (func_ == other.func_); }

    bool operator!= (const delegate& other) const
    { return !(*this == other); }

private:
    const T& callee_;
    func_type func_;
};
```

and one of the methods that I used;

```
using EventListenerDelegate = delegate<IEventDataPtr>;
using EventListenerList = std::list<EventListenerDelegate>;

bool EventManager::addListener(const EventListenerDelegate& eventDelegate, const EventType& type)
{
    // this will find or create the entry
    EventListenerList& eventListenerList = m_eventListeners[type];
    for (auto it = eventListenerList.begin(); it != eventListenerList.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (eventDelegate == (*it))
        {
            std::cout <<"Attempting to double-register a delegate" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    eventListenerList.push_back(eventDelegate);
    return true;
}
```

The code failed to compile with gcc error message;

```
error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const EventListenerDelegate {aka const delegate<std::shared_ptr<IEventData> >}' and 'delegate<std::shared_ptr<IEventData> >')
         if (eventDelegate == (*it))
                           ^
```

What should I do to fix the error?
Thank you.

EDIT:
two other specialization templates in the code;

```
//specialization for free functions
template <typename R, typename... Params>
class delegate<R (*)(Params...)>
```

and;

```
//specialization for member functions
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Params>
class delegate<R (T::*)(Params...)>
```

Comment: A `delegate<shared_ptr<..>>` is unrelated to the template specialization shown, `delegate<R (T::*)(Params...) const>` since `shared_ptr<..>` cannot be decomposed into `R (T::*)(Params...)`. Therefore, you have not shown enough code to find the problem. I even suspect this mismatch `shared_ptr` vs pointer-to-member-function is the cause of your issue.

Comment: @dyp, thanks for the reply. The two other template specializations are for free function and non-const member functions. If the cause for the error is indeed like what you've mentioned, how should I proceed to fix the issue?

Comment: Well what is `IEventData` and what is `delegate<shared_ptr<IEventData>>` trying to do?

Comment: @dyp thanks for staying with me. Basically what I'm trying to do is to follow the methods in Game Coding Complete 4th edition but using the c++11 delegates as in the article linked above instead of using fastdelegate originally. IEventData is the abstract EventData, which will be inherited by concrete implementation of the event(s). As for delegate<shared_ptr<IEventData>>, that's the helper class to bind the runtime object with the function pointer. That's how I understand it.

Comment: The issue I see here is that `delegate` wraps *function pointers*, and classes like `IEventData` are no function pointers. It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how you want to create the delegate with those classes.

Comment: @dyp I'll try to have a minimal complete example and will update my question accordingly to make it clearer. Thanks for the feedback, really appreciate it. Cheers.

Comment: None of those specializations matches `delegate<shared_ptr<IEventData>>`.